# Row count in a visual force page pdf

Tags: visualforce, controller

Can any on help me out how to get the Row count in a  visual force page  which is in a PDF format .

```
ProductName            Q1       Q2   Q3    Q4       Total
BXRC-25e4000-F-04      100     200   300   400       1000   
BXRC-25e4000-F-23      200                 200       400
Subtotal ------------  300     200   300   600       1400
```

With Code i could get the Total but the subtotal is not getting calculated correctly.Any help very much appreciated.

**Code :**

```
 public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

      public Map<String,Decimal> PartMap{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Quarter4{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount1{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount2{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount3{get;set;}

       public Map<string,Decimal> Amount4{get;set;}

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');


    }


       Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

       Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

       Public Integer quarter1subtotal{get;set;} 


       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       subtotalofquantity=0;

       subtotalofamount=0;

       quarter1subtotal=0;

      // Integer tempsubtotalofquantity=0;

     //  Integer tempsubtotalofamount=0;


     //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];



     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

    list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id Order BY gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc]; 


 //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  


        PartMap = new Map<String,Decimal>();

      //  PartMapQuantity = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter2 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Quarter4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount1 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount2= new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount3 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        Amount4 = new Map<String,Decimal>();

        for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast : opflist)
        {

             if(oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jan' || oppforecast .gmod__Month_Text__c=='Feb'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Mar'  )

                   {
                       if(Quarter1.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name ))
                             {
                                  Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                  Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount1.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                  //PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,PartMap.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);  
                              }
                        else
                              {

                                 Quarter1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                 Amount1.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                // PartMap.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__c,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                 wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                 w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                 w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                 w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                 w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                 w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                 w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                 w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                 w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                 w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                 w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                 disp_list.add(w);
                            } 
                         }

                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Apr' ||oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='May'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='June')

                          {

                               if(Quarter2.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                       {
                                           Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                           Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount2.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                        }
                              else
                                         {

                                            Quarter2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                            Amount2.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                          /* wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                            w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                            w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                            w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                            w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                            w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                            w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                            w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                            w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                            w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                            w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                            disp_list.add(w);*/

                                        }
                           }
                 if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Jul' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Aug'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Sept')

                        {

                              if(Quarter3.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                                      {
                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount3.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                                       }
                             else
                                       {

                                          Quarter3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                          Amount3.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                         /* wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                          w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                          w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                          w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                          w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                          w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                          w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                          w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                          w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                          w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                          w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                          w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                          disp_list.add(w);*/

                                    }
                            }
              if(oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Oct' || oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Nov'|| oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c=='Dec')
                      {
                          if(Quarter4.containskey(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name))
                             {
                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Quarter4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);             
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,Amount4.get(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
                             }
                     else
                             {

                                      Quarter4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                                      Amount4.put(oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name,oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);

                                     /* wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

                                      w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Product = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Quantity =oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;

                                      w.gmod_Price=oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;

                                      w.Name =oppforecast.Name;

                                      w.gmod_Quarter=oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;

                                      w.gmod_Month=oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;

                                      w.gmod_Amount=oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;

                                      w.Actual_Price=oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;

                                      w.gmod_Year=oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;

                                      w.gmod_date=oppforecast.gmod__date__c;

                                      w.gmod_Month_Text=oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

                                      w.Forecast_Date=oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;

                                     disp_list.add(w);*/
                            }

                   }


        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());



            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

           // subtotalofquantity = tempsubtotalofquantity;

            subtotalofamount+= integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);

            //subtotalofamount =tempsubtotalofamount;

            Integer quarter1subtotalTemp = Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            quarter1subtotal+=quarter1subtotalTemp;

            System.debug('qty@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ++ ' + subtotalofquantity);

            System.debug('amt############# ++ ' +subtotalofamount);

            System.debug('Qty%%%%%%%%%%% ++ ' +quarter1subtotal);


  //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c; 


                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                           //   disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
}

}
              }       
              }
         } //End of Class
```

VF Code :

```
<tr class="foot">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data" >SubTotal :</td> 
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td> 
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>
         <td colspan="1"  class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity },<br/>
             ${!subtotalofAmount },<br/></td>  
    </tr> </tr>
```

PFA Screen Shot
[image]

Comment: When I formatted your code, I found that you have a nested tr - is that just a copy paste error?

Answer (score 1):

As your iterate through your opflist, you'll need to keep track of the quarter amounts for each line row.
You'll have to define 4 `Integer` variables to hold the quarter values and add to them in each iteration of the loop.

```
Public Integer quarter1Total{get;set;}
Public Integer quarter2Total{get;set;}

quarter1Total=0;
quarter2Total=0;
```

Inside your loop:

```
Integer quarter1TotalTemp = Integer.valueOf(// ... however you get the values for each line item quarter);
quarter1Total += quarter1TotalTemp;
//etc...
```

Then put these values in your VF page and it should work. If you need help extracting these values, you'll need to provide more info about your data structure.

I have taken your code and revised it quite a bit.
Currently you are not actually displaying the results of your calculations.
Here is the revised code:

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {
    public Map < String, Decimal > PartMap {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Quarter4 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount1 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount2 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount3 {get;set;}  
    public Map < string, Decimal > Amount4 {get;set;}  
    public Competitor__c com {get;set;}  
    public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist {get;set;}  
    public Id qId {get;set;}  
    Public string all {get;set;}  

    Public QuoteContentController() {}
    Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        qId = Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
    }
        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}    
        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

        Public Integer quarter1subtotal{get;set;}     

        Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}
        subtotalofquantity = 0;
        subtotalofamount = 0;
        quarter1subtotal = 0;

        disp_list = new list < wrapperclass > ();
        //Query all the list     
        List < Quote > quotes = [select id, Name, QuoteNumber, Effective_Date__c, Comments__c, Quote.Opportunity.id,
                                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability, Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c, 
                                    Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c, Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c, Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                                    from Quote where id = : apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
        Opportunity opp = [select id, Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), 
                                probability, AccSegment__c 
                                from Opportunity where opportunity.Id = : q[0].opportunity.id LIMIT 1];
        List < gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c > opflist = [
                                Select id, Name, gmod__opportunity__r.id, gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Price__c,
                                gmod__Month__c, gmod__date__c, gmod__Quarter__c, gmod__Amount__c, Actual_Price__c, 
                                gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month_Text__c, Forecast_Date__c, gmod__Product__r.Name, 
                                gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c 
                                WHERE gmod__Product__c != null and gmod__opportunity__r.id = : opp.id 
                                Order BY gmod__Year__c, gmod__Month__c asc];
        //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        PartMap = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Quarter4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount1 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount2 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount3 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();
        Amount4 = new Map < String, Decimal > ();

        for (gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c oppforecast: opflist) {

            String prodName = oppforecast.gmod__Product__r.Name;
            String monthText = oppforecast.gmod__Month_Text__c;

            Map<String, Decimal> quarterMap;
            Map<String, Decimal> amountMap;

            if (monthText == 'Jan' || monthText == 'Feb' || monthText == 'Mar'){
                quarterMap = Quarter1;
                amountMap = Amount1;
            }
            if (monthText == 'Apr' || monthText == 'May' || monthText == 'June'){
                quarterMap = Quarter2;
                amountMap = Amount2;
            }
            if (monthText == 'Jul' || monthText == 'Aug' || monthText == 'Sept'){
                quarterMap = Quarter3;
                amountMap = Amount3;
            }
            if (monthText == 'Oct' || monthText == 'Nov' || monthText == 'Dec') {
                quarterMap = Quarter4;
                amountMap = Amount4;
            }

            if (quarterMap.containskey(prodName)) {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, quarterMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, amountMap.get(prodName) + oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            } else {
                quarterMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c);
                amountMap.put(prodName, oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c);
            }

            wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
            w.gmod_Opportunity = oppforecast.gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
            w.gmod_Product = prodName;
            w.gmod_Quantity = oppforecast.gmod__Quantity__c;
            w.gmod_Price = oppforecast.gmod__Price__c;
            w.Name = oppforecast.Name;
            w.gmod_Quarter = oppforecast.gmod__Quarter__c;
            w.gmod_Month = oppforecast.gmod__Month__c;
            w.gmod_Amount = oppforecast.gmod__Amount__c;
            w.Actual_Price = oppforecast.Actual_Price__c;
            w.gmod_Year = oppforecast.gmod__Year__c;
            w.gmod_date = oppforecast.gmod__date__c;
            w.gmod_Month_Text = monthText;
            w.Forecast_Date = oppforecast.Forecast_Date__c;
            disp_list.add(w);
        }

            for (Quote qt: quotes) {
                for (integer i = 0; i < opflist.size(); i++) {
                    subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    subtotalofamount += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c);
                    //subtotalofamount =tempsubtotalofamount;
                    Integer quarter1subtotalTemp = Integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                    quarter1subtotal += quarter1subtotalTemp;

                    //Instantiating the wrapper SObject     
                    wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database.     
                    w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;
                    w.gmod_Quantity = opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Price = opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;
                    w.Name = opflist[i].Name;
                    w.gmod_Quarter = opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;
                    w.gmod_Month = opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;
                    w.Actual_Price = opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;
                    w.gmod_Year = opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;
                    w.gmod_date = opflist[i].gmod__date__c;
                    w.gmod_Month_Text = opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;
                    w.Forecast_Date = opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Declare a wrapper class      
    public class Wrapperclass {
        //custom wrapper datatype      
        Public string Name{get;set;}  
        Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
        Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
        Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
        Public string Probability{get;set;}  
        Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
        Public string External_Comment{get;set;}      
        Public string Segment{get;set;}  
        Public string Application{get;set;}  
        Public string Persona{get;set;}  
        Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}      
        Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
        Public Decimal Total{get;set;}      
        Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
        Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
        Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
        Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
        Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
        Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
        Public string Other_information{get;set;}      
        Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
        Public string Volume{get;set;} 
        Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;}     
        Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
        Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
        Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
        Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
        Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
        Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
        Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}
    }
} //End of Class
```

You basically need to iterate through each of your Amount maps and add up all the values - into SEPARATE variables. I can see that you are trying to reuse the same variable for the each column total in your page code - there is no way that is going to work. 
Put column total variable for each column total and you should see some results.

Also, for readability, you should attempt to conform to Java coding standards - it'll make it much easier for people to help you in the future.

One final thing - since I wasn't able to compile your code, I wasn't able to sort out an extra brace that I could see was there in the code. It's not going to compile until you sort that out.

Hopefully this helps. If you are not able to work out what to do from this advice, I think you should find an expert somewhere and get them to explain to you what to do - You'll get there, it's just a matter of practice.

Good luck!

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I tried for quarter1 but it still displays the same subtotal.I have updated the code completely.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I tried the code ,the data gets repeated thrice for all the quarters and the subtotal displayed is incorrect value.Any help very much appreciated.